# Convert Tensorflow model to TFLITE format

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I've followed [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining) many times to train a model on my own images.  It works perfectly and I can then label my images fine after training.   I want to use this trained model on a Raspberry Pi Zero.

I moved the model to the pi, installed tensorflow with pip and tried to use the standard label_image.py script.   This understandably runs out of resources and dies because the model is 83MB.  I want to use tfite to slim the model down.   When I issue:

```
   toco \
    --graph_def_file=output_graph.pb \
    --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \
    --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
    --output_format=TFLITE \
    --input_array=Placeholder \
    --output_array=final_result \
    --inference_type=FLOAT \
    --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

I get a toco usage message and then just the error "toco: error: "

It's unclear to me which parameters are mandatory and what they should be.    What's the easiest way to convert a model to TFLITE for the pi zero?